# Print function not working in Flutter Stateless Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I just want to be able to print a value in my Stateless Widget, but I'm running into some errors. Here's a simplified version of my code.

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Home(),
  ));
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  print('test');
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // ... some other widgets here
    );
  }
}
```

I unfortunately keep getting these two errors.

```
Error: Expected an identifier, but got ''test''.
Try inserting an identifier before ''test''.
  print('test');
        ^^^^^^
```

```
Error: The non-abstract class 'Home' is missing implementations for these members:
 - Home.print
```

I'm very new to flutter, so any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `print` statement is outside the `build` function place it inside the function.

Like this:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('test'); //This will work
    return Scaffold(
        // ... some other widgets here
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it. So the build function kind of acts like a constructor function?

Comment: Not really. You can have a constructor - and if you want to print the comment only when the object is created, this is where you should use it, something like: ````Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key){print('test');}````Build function is called by the framework each time it draws your widget on the screen - you will see your 'test' printed multiple times while using your application.